# AsyncHTTPClient, Netty HashedWheelTimer .waitForNextTick() и четыре секунды задержки

Tags: java, netty, asynchttpclient

Пишу свой (NIH) API-клиент, используя AsyncHttpClient в качестве транспорта. Столкнулся с проблемой долгой инициализации Netty (которая входит в состав AsyncHttpClient), в логах это выглядит примерно так:

```
15:22:03.188 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
15:22:03.207 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
15:22:03.210 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
...
15:22:04.317 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
15:22:04.317 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
15:22:04.317 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
15:22:08.447 [main] DEBUG me.etki.grac.ClientBuilder - Building client
```

К моменту последней строки из моего кода вызывается только создание ClientBuilder'а и обвязок для AsyncHTTPClient, чтобы он соответствовал моим интерфейсам, т.е. всего ничего, и никаких тяжеловесных I/O операций там точно нет.

С брейкпоинтами, JVisualVM и грехом пополам удалось увидеть, что эти четыре секунды тратятся на `io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick()` (точнее, 99% загрузки за эти четыре секунды приходилось на этот метод, а *блокировать* могло что-то другое). Про safe points знаю, нормальным профайлером пока что обдавать это дело не приходилось - это просто минимум информации, которую удалось собрать.

Вопрос: как мне выяснить причину утечки времени старта? Может, кто-то уже имел аналогичные проблемы с Netty?